# DecimalFormat results in two different results on different machines

Tags: java, numbers, number-formatting, bigdecimal, decimalformat

I was analyzing case where `DecimalFormat` rounded one `BigDecimal` number and on other machine, it is truncated.

I have verified all configurations on both machines (and all are same, i assume).
Only difference which i have figured out is JDK version.

Machine 1 is running on JDK1.6 . But, i have tried same with JDK1.7 on Machine 1, it is working same as with JDK1.6.

Machine 2 is running on JDK1.7

Following is the code snippet:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
BigDecimal anObject = new BigDecimal("3.8880");
String str = decimalFormat.format(((Number)anObject).doubleValue());
System.out.println(str);
```

On Machine 1 Result is : 3.39

On Machine 2 result is : 3.38

Comment: I don't see how the number 3.8880 could be rounded or truncated to 3.38 or 3.39. Do you mean 3.88/3.89? Or didn't you do the test correctly?

Comment: Try to run on command prompt "java -version". Maybe just a JVM bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a bug introduced in JDK7 on `DecimalFormat`.
See this question for more information: [Is inconsistency in rounding between Java 7 and Java 8 a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797964/is-inconsistency-in-rounding-between-java-7-and-java-8-a-bug)

Comment: Thanks Arnaud, I have checked it on oracle site too and found same bug reported there also. Check this reference [Bug on Oracle](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8039915) site