# Java 8 DecimalFormat gives inconsistent output

Tags: java, java-8, format

JDK 8

```
DecimalFormat x = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
System.out.println(x.format(4.4804));
System.out.println(x.format(4.4805));
System.out.println(x.format(4.5805));
System.out.println(x.format(4.5804));
```

Output

```
4.480
4.481
4.580
4.580
```

I am aware about the [JDK7 bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797964/is-inconsistency-in-rounding-between-java-7-and-java-8-a-bug). But even in JDK 8 it is not consistent. am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Print `new BigDecimal(4.5805).toString()` and `new BigDecimal(4.4805).toString()` to see there is no bug here and this is behaving exactly like described in the linked question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by the comment to the question, your observed results are caused by your numeric literals being interpreted as `double` values which may not be represented exactly, e.g.,

```java
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(4.4805).toString());
```

produces

```
4.48050000000000014921397450962103903293609619140625
```

which is then rounded to `4.481` because it is *just past* the half-way point between `4.480` and `4.481`. You will see more consistent results if you tweak your code sample to

```java
DecimalFormat x = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
System.out.println(x.format(new BigDecimal("4.4804")));
System.out.println(x.format(new BigDecimal("4.4805")));
System.out.println(x.format(new BigDecimal("4.5805")));
System.out.println(x.format(new BigDecimal("4.5804")));
```