# DecimalFormat.format in Java - Rounding to 2 decimal error

Tags: java, java-8, java-7

In JDK 1.7, Decimalformat(0.00).format(0.045) gives the output 0.05

In JDK 1.8, Decimalformat(0.00).format(0.045) gives the output 0.04

Please let me know why there is a rounding issue to 2 decimal places. Which one is correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is inconsistency in rounding between Java 7 and Java 8 a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797964/is-inconsistency-in-rounding-between-java-7-and-java-8-a-bug)

Comment: I would think the 1.8 is the more correct.  Formatting shouldn't modify the base data.  If the user intended for the data to be rounded then they'd perform such operations prior to formatting.